# Bootstrap 5.2 'form-floating' class issue/question

Tags: css, webforms, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap 5.2, and I have a form that includes the following form snippet:

```
<div class="row mb-2 align-items-center">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label class="checkbox-inline" for="Credit_Pulled">Credit Pulled</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-inline" value="1" name="Credit_Pulled" id="Credit_Pulled">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label class="checkbox-inline" for="Is_On_Terms">Approved For Terms</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="align-middle" value="true" name="Is_On_Terms" id="Is_On_Terms">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 form-floating">
                            <label for="Terms_Days">Terms Period</label>
                            <select class="form-select form-control d-flex" id="Terms_Days" name="Terms_Days">
                                <option value="0" selected>NONE</option>
                                <option value="30">NET-30</option>
                                <option value="60">NET-60</option>
                                <option value="90">NET-90</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mb-2">
                        <div class="col-sm-4 form-floating">
                            <label for="Credit_Limit">Approved Limit</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control d-flex" id="Credit_Limit" name="Credit_Limit">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mb-2">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 w-100 form-floating">
                            <label for="Review_Notes">Review Notes</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control rounded" rows="8" id="Review_Notes" name="Review_Notes"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

When I view the form, this is what I get:

[image: Output from code above]

The problem is, the form labels and their contents overlap.  Is there any way (even by adding custom CSS) to prevent this so that they display cleanly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap docs says that the `<label>` needs to come after the `<input>` https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/floating-labels/

Comment: Huh.  That was it.  How crazy...But thank you!  Answer accepted!  Guess I should read the docs a bit more closely, eh? (grin)

Comment: Your welcome. I figured it out (after a while) when I inspected the images in the dev-tools. I knew they had to be 100% width but they weren't. So, yeah, I went to the docs.